# Generate K random numpy arrays given N variables and ranges

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, distribution

I have N variables (defining N-dimensional space), with their defined ranges (normally or uniformly distributed in the given range):

each variable is defined by a list containing its possible integer values.

```
v1_range = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
v2_range = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
v3_range = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
v4_range = [15, 16, 17, 18]
```

i want to generate K lists (numpy arrays/vectors..), each list contains one random number from the given ranges, **with no duplicates**.
so i-th element in each list, is selected from i-th list of ranges.

example (K = 6, from given ranges):

```
output = [
    [1, 20, 300, 15],
    [5, 10, 200, 15],
    [3, 60, 100, 18],
    [4, 30, 200, 16],
    [4, 40, 100, 17],
    [2, 30, 400, 15],
]
```

What is the best way to do so,using `numpy.random()` or `scipy`  assuming the N-dimensional space could be very large (~13 lists of ranges, each containing ~20 values) and no duplicates are allowed ?

[EDIT]
duplicate entries in the ranges lists are fine, but i don't want to have two duplicate/exact same lists in the resulting list of lists e.g.:

indices 0, 2 are duplicated...

```
res = [[  4,  40, 400,  18],
       [  4,  60, 400,  17],
       [  4,  40, 400,  18]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Will simple iteration work? I think for 13 lists x 20 values it will work just fine.

```
import random

d = {
"v1_range" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
"v2_range" : [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
"v3_range" : [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
"v4_range" : [15, 16, 17, 18]
}

def give(k):
    out = [[] for i in range(k)]
    for l in out:
        for i in d.keys():
            l.append(random.choice(d[i]))
    return out
```

Which gives, for example:

```
>>> give(6)
[[5, 50, 500, 15], [1, 60, 400, 16], [5, 20, 200, 15], [1, 40, 400, 18], [2, 20, 100, 15], [6, 20, 400, 16]]
```

Or, with numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(give(6))
array([[  4,  40, 400,  18],
       [  4,  60, 400,  17],
       [  5,  20, 400,  17],
       [  4,  10, 300,  16],
       [  5,  10, 300,  16],
       [  4,  30, 500,  18]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that'll do for the most part, but does this also handle the duplicates?

Comment: @MohammedErow Can you please elaborate on duplicates? Can your lists have duplicated entries between each other?